# How to create/delete HDI cluster using Java in Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-hdinsight

I am running a sequence spark jobs on HDI cluster. I need HDI cluster to be available for test running time alone. So I want to do the following using Java

- Create HDI cluster
- Run my tests
- Delete HDI cluster

How can I do the above using Java program in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Azure does not provide Java SDK for HDI cluster.

But you could use Rest API to create and delete HDI cluster.

[Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/hdinsight-cluster#create)

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription Id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup Name}/providers/Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/{cluster name}?api-version={api-version}
```

[Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/hdinsight-cluster#delete)

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription Id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup Name}/providers/Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/{cluster name}?api-version={api-version}
```

In java, you could write a program to call these API.

Comment: Maybe this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/) is helpful.

Comment: 1. I believe we need to pass request json data in PUT and not in DELETE. Am I right? 2.  Will Java SDK support Azure SQL DWH? 3. What are the Azure resources supported in Java SDK.

Comment: 1.Create Hdi clustet with PUT

Comment: First question, you are right. When you create a cluster, you need use method PUT.  Second and third question you could check [Java library for Azure](https://github.com/azure/azure-libraries-for-java).

Comment: I don't see an HDInsight support in Java SDK. Is there any sample available for create/delete cluster in c# Azure Functions.

Comment: @karan Yes, currently java SDK does not support HDInsight, so if you want to create it with java, you could call rest API.

Comment: @karan C# is supported. This is a [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-dotnet-sdk).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, these are different methods you can use to set up an HDInsight cluster.

[image]

For more details, refer "[Set up clusters in HDInsight with Hadoop, Spark, Kafka, and more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-provision-linux-clusters?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fhdinsight%2Fhadoop%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)".

You may leave you feedback here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.